# mapbox-gl-js addWaypoint why does it have map load event called?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am using mapbox-gl-js and mapbox-gl-directions plugins.

Unfortunately the plugin repo looks like it is abandoned; nobody is answering our issues on GitHub.

mapbox-gl-directions plugin has function `addWaypoint` and it doesn't have `addWaypoint(s)`. So I can only add one `waypoint` at a time. So I need for loop my points and call `addWaypoint` each time. Look what the function(addWaypoint) says in the repository's docs:

> "Add a waypoint to the route. Note: calling this method requires the
> map load event to have run."

So map load event runs and I lose the idea of mapbox gl which is cheaper for pricing. After looking through src code, I can see that it only creates one API call after I set the destination. So I don't understand why the docs say the above thing about map load each time when `addWaypoint` is called.

Do you think map load event still runs for adding each Waypoint? If the answer is yes, then what's the point of using mapbox-gl-js which states pricing is for map load and not each tile request?

Comment: My reading of that statement is that you can't run `addWaypoint` until after the map has loaded. I don't read it that you have to load the map each time.

Comment: I think you're correct. My Bad.

Answer (score 1):

@peeebeee is correct, you just need to make sure that you only call mapbox-gl-direction's `addWaypoint` after the GL JS's Map `load` event has been called https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map.event:load. This is a different thing to the "map load" billing unit.

```
map.on('load', function () {
  directions.addWaypoint(...)
})
```